# 2.7-4.2 V Li-Ion battery to 5 V 5 A converter

Tags: lithium-ion, boost, batteries

I have a 2.7-4.2 V Li-Ion battery. I want to convert this battery to boost 5 V-5 A power supply for a short time usage.

I know there are lots of ICs to convert these values but I need advice for which one. I don't have an external bias voltage to feed the IC. Should I use an IC output voltage as a bias voltage? Or should I feed bias voltage somehow and use the output voltage as bias voltage?

For example LTC7804 input range is 4.5-40 V. To operate at 2.7 V LTC7804 needs 4.5 V bias voltage. (**It operates down to 1 V after start-up.**)

Comment: GD4142 might work, but the output using it is just 1a

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for help, I just joined the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I know there are lots of ICs to convert these values but I need advice
> for which one.*

Specific product recommendation requests are off-topic but, here are a few words that might help you target a solution: -

You need to find a boost converter circuit (a type of switching regulator) that works with an input voltage down to 2.7 volts and can still regulate 5 volts on the output at 5 amps of load current. Of course your battery needs to be able to supply 10 amps (at about 2.7 volts) to achieve this load current.

The normal suppliers/vendors/distributors in your country should have dozens of different options and, they usually have pretty good search engines too.

> *I don't have an external bias voltage to feed the IC.*

You don't need one; it should run directly from the battery (providing your battery can supply the current without burning). The LTC7804 is probably not what you should be looking at and, now that you have found the ADI webpage, you should be able to use their search engines. Here's a part that's getting close to what you might use: -
$$$$

[image]

I found the part above using this [ADI search engine](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11389#/p5362=Boost%7CBuck-Boost&p5573=2.2%7C2.6&p5574=4.5%7Cmax&p5357=5%7Cmax&p5358=16%7C60&p5349=5%7C50&qsfv=vinmin%7C2.6_vinmax%7C4.5_vout%7C5_iout%7C5&p5351=1%7C1). Good hunting and, remember there are other vendors.